# JSP load different jsp file from sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have a index.jsp with a sidebar:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<li ><a href="create">Create</a></li>
<li ><a href="view">View</a></li>
<li ><a href="Delete">Delete</a></li>
</div>
```

Currently selecting from the sidebar will go to the jsp file let say create.jsp and from there it will run the

```
$("#sidebar").load("index");
```

to load the sidebar.  What I want is when I select any from the sidebar menu it will instead load the create.jsp from the index.jsp:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<li ><a href="create">Create</a></li>
<li ><a href="view">View</a></li>
<li ><a href="Delete">Delete</a></li>
</div>

<div>
$("#selectedmenu").load("create"); 
</div>
```

Is this possible in jsp?

Comment: So we are talking about JavaServer Pages. Right? Because i only see html/jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the mistake
    instead of

```
 $("#selectedmenu").load("create");
```

make it like this

```
   <script>
         $("#selectedmenu").load("create"); 
</script>
```